# I want to add radiobutton programatically and set first item being selected?

Tags: android, json, arraylist, radio-button, android-radiogroup

Here is my code which I created bunch of radio buttons from my Json.

```
for (int i = 0; i < level_array_list.size(); i++) {
    RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(getActivity());
    radioButton.setText(level_array_list.get(i).getLevelName());
    radioButton.setId(Integer.parseInt(level_array_list.get(i).getLevel_id()));
    radioGrp.addView(radioButton);
}
```

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: *`i am stucked here`* what is the exact problem

Comment: i want to be selected first item which is loaded from json array ? i cant able to do that

Answer (score 0):

> i want to be selected first item which is loaded from json array ?

You need to use **`radioButton.setChecked(true);`** inside loop when **`i = 0`** (means first radio button)

Try this

```
 for (int i = 0; i < level_array_list.size(); i++) {
            RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(getActivity());
            radioButton.setText(level_array_list.get(i).getLevelName());
            radioButton.setId(Integer.parseInt(level_array_list.get(i).getLevel_id()));
            if(i==0){
                radioButton.setChecked(true);
            }
            radioGrp.addView(radioButton);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. This will checked the first item. Hope it helps!

```
ArrayList<RadioButton> radioButtonsList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < level_array_list.size(); i++) {
        RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(getActivity());
        radioButton.setText(level_array_list.get(i).getLevelName());
        radioButton.setId(Integer.parseInt(level_array_list.get(i).getLevel_id()));
        radioButtonsList.add(radioButton);
        radioGrp.addView(radioButton);
    }

RadioButton radioButton = radioButtonsList.get(0);
radioButton.setChecked(true);
```